# how to retain subfolder in zip command

Tags: linux, shell, zip, robotframework

```
test
    |
    subFolder
        |
        -a.text
        -b.text
```

We have above folder structure and we want to create a zip file containing subfolder and files when we execute below commands using robot it eliminates subFolder and puts files in test.zip kindly suggest some good way to retain the subFolder containing files

```
OS.Run    [ -f ${SC_HOME}/test.zip ] || zip -j ${SC_HOME}/test.zip ${SC_HOME}/test/*
```

Comment: can someone help me to fix this ??

Answer (score 0):

OS.Run    [ -f ${SC_HOME}/test.zip ] || cd  ${SC_HOME}; zip -j test.zip test/*; cd /